# goal seek in VBA on a specific worksheet (disabling calculation in other opened files)

Tags: vba

i have a quick question about running goal seek in VBA within an excel worksheet. I'm noticing that when i have other workbooks opened within the same excel session the goalseek in the workbook/worksheet i am trying to run takes longer (i am guessing it is because excel calculates the other opened workbooks.

is there a way to disable excel from calculating the other opened workbooks?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its also possible to bypass the problem a couple of ways (both have downsides)
1. set the .EnableCalculation property to False for all the worksheets that are not involved in the formulas linking the goal-seek target cell to the Goal-seek cell-to-be-changed (including the worksheets in the other workbooks)
(This is the method used in my FastExcel product for Active Workbook calculation mode.)
2. Write your own VBA goalseek routine and use Range.Calculate to calculate all the cells in the path bewteen the 2 goalseek cells, or if its all on one sheet use Worksheet.calculate

Comment: I like the sound of your 1 solution.. I googled around and found some code that almost does what you are referring to but how can I expand this code to include worksheets in other opened files? I am not that great at coding. Found code here http://www.ozgrid.com/forum/showthread.php?t=121255&page=1

Comment: This is the code i am referring to within that link `code` Sub TryThisApproach() <br/>   'Change Sheet1 to the code name for the sheet you want to calculate <br/> Dim ws As Worksheet <br/> For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets <br/> If Not ws Is Sheet1 Then ws.EnableCalculation = False <br/> Next ws <br/> 'run the goal seek code for Sheet1 <br/> For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets <br/> If Not ws Is Sheet1 Then ws.EnableCalculation = True <br/> Next ws <br/> End Sub <br/> `code`

Answer (score 0):

Excel calculation is done at the application level (all open workbooks). So you should switch calculation to manual calculation mode, run the goalseek and then switch back to automatic or use Application.Calculate.
 Even then just the fact of having extra workbooks open gives Excel a larger overhead and so will be slower.

Comment: thanks Charles for this answer, but my excel session is always setup to run as manual... too bad there is no way to avoid all open workbooks from calculating when running a goalseek in an independent workbook.